# Convert data into same unit in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1UDb.png)

there are different unit for size : like k for 1,000, M for mega. I want to convert all data into same unit - bytes

may i know how to make it?

The expected result is update the size column into bytes like 9k will be 9,000

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_unit(value):
    if value in "kb":
        #convert to bytes      
        return bytes
    elif value in "mb":
        # convert to bytes
        return bytes

# the above function is just an example

df['column'].map(convert_unit)
```

You can map all the column values using the function. Redefine the function as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work if your data is consitent:

```
def func(val):
    # get the string suffix ('K'/'M')
    val_char = val[-1:].lower()
    if val_char == 'k':
        return int(val[:-1]) * 1_000
    elif val_char == 'm':
        return int(val[:-1]) * 1_000_000
    else:
        return 0

df['size_bytes'] = df['size'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```